# Title of music in Psycho-Pass ep 04

Tags: anime, music-identification

I have been searching online for many hours if the music that plays in episode 4 of *[Psycho-Pass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psycho-Pass)* from 16:11 to 18:11 (visit to the EXOSET disco) exists. What is the title of the music?

https://www.bilibili.tv/en/video/2014363014

Comment: It sounds like a bit of a generic techno sound loop to me, but for those researching, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rg5FGT0qkz8 and https://psychopass.fandom.com/wiki/Psycho-Pass_Original_Soundtrack might be handy.

Comment: It sounds like in-house music production. Just some generic sampling

Comment: Parts of it sound like a variant of [Crime Coefficient](https://youtu.be/rg5FGT0qkz8?t=887), but I won't swear to it.

Comment: Merci pour les recherches les gars !

Comment: Elle est pas ouf sérieux la bande son ? Je l'écoute en boucle depuis 3 jours meme si ya les voix ^^

Comment: Si c'est une production interne c'est dommage ...